# IBM MobileFirst on Eclipse Juno, Error when trying to preview or deploy

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

[ERROR   ] FWLSE3002E: The resource is not found.
FWLSE3030E: The runtime "P1" does not exist in the MobileFirst administration database. The database may be corrupted.

I use java 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse Java EE Juno is *not supported* by IBM MobileFirst Platform 6.3 and above.

Upgrade to either Eclipse Java EE Kepler (4.3.x) or Luna (4.4.x) and try again using a fresh workspace.

Comment: thanks, 
should I download the IBM MobileFirst again for the new eclipse version ?

Comment: Download the appropriate eclipse version and then reinstall mfp.